Poor Wireless Performance using Intel AX210 Wireless and 24.04 LTS
I have a PC fitted with a Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210, the machine is dual boot, under Windows I get great performance > 100 Mb/s download from my provider but under Ubuntu I see less than < 2Mb/s.
I found a tonne of posts with other users having similar issues and in summary I've tried the following:

Updated / Upgraded Packages
Updated / Linux-Firmware
Disable Power Management
Disable 802.11ax (tried option 8 and 1)
Latest Intel Firmware Drivers

I've gathered this information to see if anyone can see or suggest anything else I can try:
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Oct 2024 21:00 BST +0100

Booted last: 13 Oct 2024 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 27 Aug 2024 10:55 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard LAN Brodcom
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: igc

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak] [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                864256  0
mac80211             1720320  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               598016  1 iwlmvm
wmi_bmof               12288  0
cfg80211             1323008  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    28672  2 video,wmi_bmof

##### dkms #############################

./wireless-info: line 206: dkms: command not found

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    altname enp2s0
    inet 192.168.1.37/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 86065sec preferred_lft 86065sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'eno1' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.32/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 86225sec preferred_lft 86225sec
    inet6 fe80::6213:df5b:f141:e24f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxxxxxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'xxxxxxx' [AN1]>   
          Bit Rate=14.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:14   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.32 metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.32 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         941       1  0 20:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               86.fb5c9aeb.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-86.uc
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     xxxxxxx
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e7d5d4c3-ac90-4d5d-8b9a-4ec9e697dfde
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     14 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.6GHZ:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.32/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1728935877
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.32
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6213:df5b:f141:e24f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e7d5d4c3-ac90-4d5d-8b9a-4ec9e697dfde | xxxxxx

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Controller I225-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         igc
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               1045:740
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     netplan-eno1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       10838d80-caeb-349e-ba73-08ed16d4d666
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1728935717
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.37
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'eno1' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   10838d80-caeb-349e-ba73-08ed16d4d666 | netplan-eno1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                       BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

grep: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-e7d5d4c3-ac90-4d5d-8b9a-4ec9e697dfde.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Input/output error

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,iwlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       6.8.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       6.8.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11be:Disable EHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.8.0-45-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
disable_11be: N
enable_ini: 16
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  459.251907] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[  459.793681] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[  459.946716] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[  459.946753] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[  459.946783] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[  459.946799] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0

########## wireless info END ############

I'd really appreciate someone taking the time to take a look or letting me know if they've solved this problem with the Intel AX 210 Wireless Card's performance.

You say you have disabled power management but the script shows it being active

OK, let me check that - it might have got rolled back as part of testing process I was following - I'll come back to you today.

Under section [iwlwifi] - I see power_save: N.
Have I got turned off the power saving in the right place ? Any chance you could confirm for me the process I should follow to make sure I've done this correctly ?

In terminal do sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off  and sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and see if it improves

I've done those and did a reboot and the performance is still the same here is a link to the revised wireless info (thanks for these scripts BTW) https://termbin.com/yywkw

Can you disable secure boot and try installing the 6.11 kernel from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.11/ You will likely need to download and install the 4 amd64 files and install.  A search said some issues with these Intel devices was fixed in 6.11

I've applied the 6.11 kernel and it resolved the issue, also weirdly resolved another issue I was having trying to get Docker Desktop to work so that was a bonus, many thanks for the assistance @Jeremy31

@Jeremy31 - its been a while, I can't remember how to mark your comment as the answer.

You can't accept a comment as an answer

Applied the 6.11 kernel using the instructions from here:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/08/install-latest-kernel-new-repository/#:~:text=Install%20Latest%20Kernel%20in%20Ubuntu%20via%20new%20Repository,Install%20Newest%20Kernel%20...%204%204.%20Verify%20
It resolved the issue, also weirdly resolved another issue I was having trying to get Docker Desktop to work so that was a bonus, many thanks for the assistance @Jeremy31
