Asus vivobook wifi adaptar issue
I recently installed ubuntu 24.04 lts in my (Asus Vivobook Go 15 E1504FA) Everything works fine but the wifi driver is not detected by the OS. My laptop does not even have ethernet port. The wifi driver works fine in windows and it has no hardware issues.
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Firmware Update: I cloned the latest linux-firmware repository and copied the mediatek firmware files to /lib/firmware/mediatek/.
Driver Installation: I attempted to load the mt7921e driver with the following commands:
sudo modprobe mt7921e
sudo modprobe -r mt7921e and sudo modprobe mt7921e again
Check Network Status:
lshw -C network shows the Wi-Fi card as "UNCLAIMED."
iwconfig shows no wireless extensions.
System Logs: I couldn't find any helpful output from dmesg | grep mt7921e.
Despite these efforts, the Wi-Fi driver doesn't seem to load, and the network interface remains unclaimed.
Could anyone guide me on how to get my Wi-Fi working on Ubuntu? I'm using kernel version 6.8.0-51-generic.
Please help me to fix this and get my wifi drivers working on Ubuntu.

Please attach output of this terminal command: lspci -nnk -d ::0280

From research from you rig https://www.asus.com/uk/laptops/for-home/vivobook/vivobook-go-15-oled-e1504f/#section__15/ you are using WiFi 6E
802.11ax  if so take a look at the answers here: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525695/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error-after-upgrade-from-22-04-4-to-24-04-1 and https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Wifi-not-working-on-Ubuntu-for-AX210/m-p/1590829 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529892/poor-wireless-performance-using-intel-ax210-wireless-and-24-04-lts Sadly, the fix seems to be a more advanced kernel which might not be so easy to install.

@david I tried these fixes, and they are still not working. Help me out
